# Getting last item this line using python

Tags: python

I have output `['Q 0006 005C 0078 0030 0030 0033 0034 ONE_OF 0002 ']` I want only 0002 last item in this and how to remove these [' '] from the output

Comment: You know you could just read a tutorial http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Comment: Is it a list with one string or a string with quotes and brackets? Use the correct formatting options when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming input is a list:

```
>>> x=['Q 0006 005C 0078 0030 0030 0033 0034 ONE_OF 0002 ']
>>> x[0].split()[-1].strip()
'0002'
```

or if it's a string :

```
>>> x="['Q 0006 005C 0078 0030 0030 0033 0034 ONE_OF 0002 ']"
>>> x.split()[-2].strip()
'0002'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> 'Q 0006 005C 0078 0030 0030 0033 0034 ONE_OF 0002 '.split()[-1]
'0002'
```